# declarative authorization and mongoid embedded documents

Tags: mongoid, declarative-authorization

I'm using declarative authorization and mongoid. I have association as

```
Class Company
  embeds_many :divisions
end

Class Division
 embedded_in :company
end
```

and route as

```
resources :companies do
 resources :divisions
end
```

I added `filter_resource_access` in my `divisions_controller.rb`. Permission for division index is ok, but while editing and updating declarative authorization query with division id raising error `Document not found for class Division with id(s) 13244adsf32gag3`.
How would I make it work with embedded controller and documents too?